# Capturing the exit code of sourced shell script without breaking the current script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have two shell scripts:

test.sh

```
function func() {
echo $1
exit 1
}
```

run.sh

```
source ./test.sh

func "Hello"
exitCode=$?
echo "Output: ${exitCode}"
```

Result:

```
Hello
```

The current problem which I'm facing is that when the function func returns 1, my run.sh script breaks and nothing gets executed after it. So, is there any way I can effectively capture the exit code without breaking run.sh. Since I can't modify the test.sh script, I have to find a way to do it in my run.sh. I tried using `flock` to execute the script but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: You should `return` instead of `exit` in the function, if you have control over that code.

Comment: I don't have privileges to change that script that's why I am looking for an option to do it within my script.

Comment: Oh, you actually say that in the question text. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need environmental changes, you can run the function in a subshell. This makes the `exit` apply only to the `( .. )` and not your main script:

```
source ./test.sh

( func "Hello" )
exitCode=$?
echo "Output: ${exitCode}"
```

Comment: Thanks that does works but is there a way I can do it using flock to ensure that the code runs without invoking sub-shell

Comment: There are various hacks to do it without a subshell, such as `alias exit=return`, but no, you can't do this with `flock`. The problem is unrelated to file locking.